# Java- Looping through through an array with instance variables in constructors

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I have to write this program which has the class Ant:

- The default constructor initialises the instance variables queens to
  only 1 queen named “Beth” and colonySize to 100,000.
- The defined constructor takes in two parameters and initialises the
  corresponding instance variables.
- The method display, shows the information about an ant in the format
  below:

  ```
  This ant colony has the following queens:
  Queen 1: Beth
  The colour of the ants: black
  The approximate colony size: 100000
  ```

Here is the **Class Ants** I have written for this:

```
public class Ant {

private String[] queens= new String [1];
public String colour= "black";
private int colonySize;


public Ant(){

    queens[0]= "Beth";
    colonySize= 100000;
}

public Ant(String[] queens, int colonySize){
    this.queens[0]= queens[0];
    this.colonySize= colonySize;
}

public void display(){
    for(int i=0; i<queens.length;i++){
        System.out.println("Queen "+ (i+1) +":" + queens[i]);   
    }
    System.out.println("The colour of the ants: "+ this.colour);
    System.out.println("The approximate size of the colony: "+ this.colonySize);
    }
}
```

Then the class FireAnts extends the class Ants whereby

- The defined constructor takes in two parameters and initialises the relevant
  instance variables. It then sets the colour of the ants to “red” and the
  venomous instance variable to true.
- The method display, shows the information about a fire ant in the format
  below:

  ```
  This ant colony has the following queens:
  Queen 1: Lilith
  Queen 2: Maya
  The colour of the ants: red
  The approximate colony size: 250000
  The Fire ants are: venomous
  ```

**Class FireAnts:**

```
public class FireAnt extends Ant {

private boolean venomous;

public FireAnt(String[] queens, int colonySize){

    super(new String[]{"Lilith", "Maya"}, 250000);
    super.colour= "red";
    this.venomous= true;
}

    public void display(){
        super.display();
        if(this.venomous=true){
        System.out.println("The ants are: venomous");}
    }

}
```

The class MainAnts which initialises an array ants with the following:

i) A FireAnt colony with two queens named Lilith and Maya respectively and
having a colony size of 250,000 ants.

ii) An Ant

and displays the following when it is run:

```
This ant colony has the following queens: 
Queen 1: Lilith 
Queen 2: Maya 
The colour of the ants: red 
The approximate colony size: 250000 
The Fire ants are: venomous

This ant colony has the following queens:
Queen 1: Beth
The colour of the ants: black
The approximate colony size: 100000
```

**Class MainAnts:**

```
public class MainAnts {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Ant obj[]= new Ant[2];


    obj[0]= new Ant();
    obj[1]= new FireAnt(new String[]{"Lilith", "Maya"}, 250000);

for(int i=0; i<2;i++){
    obj[i].display();
    System.out.println();
}


 }
}
```

The thing is that when I am running the program only the first Queen from FireAnts is being printed. Below is the output when the main class is run.

```
This ant colony has the following queens: 
Queen 1: Lilith 
The colour of the ants: red 
The approximate colony size: 250000 
The Fire ants are: venomous

This ant colony has the following queens:
Queen 1: Beth
The colour of the ants: black
The approximate colony size: 100000
```

I suppose it's because in the Ants class, I have set queen to the first element in the array. 
I also want to know how the boolean variable `venomous` can be printed out when it is set to `true` instead of hardcoding it. Can't figure out how to fix these 2 things.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, I would like suggestions and improvements in the program.

Thanks.

Comment: Elliott's answer should fix your issues. Consider renaming your classes to `AntColony` and `FireAntColony` as the objects don't actually represent a single ant.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `Ant` constructor, you only copy the first `queen`. Change

```
public Ant(String[] queens, int colonySize){
    this.queens[0]= queens[0];
    this.colonySize= colonySize;
}
```

to

```
public Ant(String[] queens, int colonySize){
    this.queens = queens;
    this.colonySize= colonySize;
}
```

And, change

```
super(new String[]{"Lilith", "Maya"}, 250000);
```

to

```
super(queens, colonySize);
```

Finally, as to your `venomous` question, one `=` is assignment; you need two for equality.

```
if(this.venomous=true){
```

should be

```
if(this.venomous==true){
```

**or** just

```
if(this.venomous){
```

Comment: Thank you for the above solution. Actually, for the venomous part, I meant how can I print it like this `System.out.println("The ants are: "+this.venomous)`. Well, if it's possible to access a boolean this way.

Comment: @Diksha You could use the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). `System.out.println("The ants are: " + (this.venomous ? "venomous" : "not venemous"))`